# App working only on some devices, how to fix it

Tags: android-studio, android-8.0-oreo

I'm developing an app where you have a deck of cards which you decide, and when you start a game every player receive a card. Every card says the owner's role and during the game you have to call some characters. To call this people i created a listview that show "name - role - status(alive/dead)". Clicking on an item a new activity will be opened where you see/do what that character have/can do. And here is where i have the problem. On my emulator it works properly and some days ago all my devices could use the app but now it is giving problems. I tried this app on 3 devices. The first one is android 5.1.1, and when you click on an item, the app crash. It doesn't matter which one you click. The second is android 8, and with some item, it doesn't work properly. For example with an item you should see 3 buttons. Well you can't see these buttons. And last phone is android 9, the only one which can use app properly. What's the problem? Is a code problem? Is a compatibility problem? But I'm not using any api.

I tried deleting app, and reinstalling the app multiple times. I tried to find something online but i didn't find something.

```
//Activity opened when you click on an item
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_chiamata_notte);

            // ... Inizialize buttons ... 
            // ... Inizialize textview ...

            // Inizialize an object card that i need to know which card is selected
            carta = new Carta(PlayActivity2.cartaSelezionata.getName(), 
            PlayActivity2.cartaSelezionata.getDesc(), 
            PlayActivity2.cartaSelezionata.getScore());
            // Inizialize a String that i need to do know which player is selected
            giocatore = PlayActivity2.giocatoreSelezionato;

            // Inizialize an arraylist with all players
            giocatori = new ArrayList<>(PlayActivity2.mazzoGiorno);

            // Inizialize list view
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewChiamataNotte);

            // Inizialize adapter
            adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(chiamataNotte.this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.txtitem, giocatori);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            // And i make it invisible because now all characters have to see the list
            listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            // When you click on a character you check which card is it
            // This is just the first one
            if(carta.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Allevatore di lupi")){
                chiamataNotteTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                chiamataNotteTextView.setText("Far conoscere all'allevatore di lupi i lupi senza che loro vedano lui");
            } ... More options for cards ...
```

So i would like to understand how to fix this problem that don't allow me to use this app on my all devices. Error with first device:

> "The program *name* has been closed"

Comment: Have you searched the logs for error? Or you can edit your questions and post the logs here as well.

Comment: Are logs from this fuction ok?
`try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                log.append(line);
            }
          // Copy into clipboard
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }`
Do you want logs on every device before and after click the item?

Comment: I mean, if you search the logs, you may find the reason behind the error...

Comment: If you mean android studio logcat, i can see it only with the emulator (where the app work properly). When i use app on my device i install app without use android studio (i mean, i create the apk, then i install that on my devices). Should i post emulator logs anyway? Which part? Sorry but i have never use logs